# Netezza Output Formatting

Tags: sql, netezza

Does anyone know how to reformat output based on field value for Netezza?

I am currently using this syntax to export data.

```
\a \t \f , \o export_ntz.txt SELECT field1,field2,field3,field4 FROM tb_normal \o
```

Current Result will be like this:

```
1234 , 123A , 12    , 123A
ASd2 , 123s , 312   , 123A
```

I just want to reformatted printed field as per example below:

```
1234,123A,12 ,123A
ASd2,123s,312,123A
```

Noted:- Length size for field1 is 4 and field3 is 3, so what option to added in my query to make my result will be fix printed as size of column?

Comment: are the columns char or varchar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data doesn't have padding in it the following export should work fine

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE 'full_file_path\export_ntz.txt' USING (DELIM ',') AS
SELECT field1,field2,field3,field4 FROM tb_normal;
```

Comment: trying your SQL, but it return Relative path does not allowed. Scene i don`t have a data padding but if data is null and I want to printed padding as per length of value, it is such a way?

Comment: Sure `SELECT nvl(field1,repeat(' ',5)),nvl(field2,repeat(' ',5)),nvl(field3,repeat(' ',5)),nvl(field4,repeat(' ',5)) FROM tb_normal;`

Comment: or: `SELECT substr(rpad(nvl(field1,''),4),1,4),substr(rpad(nvl(field2,''),3),1,3),substr(rpad(nvl(field3,''),3),1,3),substr(rpad(nvl(field4,''),3),1,3) FROM tb_normal;`

Comment: Thanks Niederee, i am really appreciated it. Need to add \a to unformat aligned.